# How to compile c++ code with exceptions in except-disabled build process

Tags: c++, exception, makefile, build-process

Our system do not use c++ exceptions. Recently I am porting a third party code which uses c++ exceptions, e.g., there is some exceptions 
throw about memory allocations, etc.

Can I handle such case, without changing the "third party" code?

Comment: I think that you're limited to 3 options: 1) Start using c++ exceptions 2) Modify third party code to not use exceptions 3) Don't use third party code that uses exceptions.

Comment: 1) is not possible: cannot enable exception in our massive legacy code just for this third party code; 2) third party code use exceptions quite a few places, if I change, how to sync with the upstream 3) then I have to find some alternative lib

Comment: I suppose you could 4) write a wrapper for the library that catches any exceptions but doesn't throw any, build the wrapper and the third party library with `-fexceptions` and use the wrapper in the legacy code... but I have no idea if that's allowed.

Comment: Umm... *Why* can't you enable exceptions in your massive legacy code? You won't have to change the massive legacy code, you'll simply have to decide what you want the combined codebase to do if/when the third-party code throws an exception, and write wrappers accordingly. Simplest wrapper: no wrapper at all, an exception will cause the code to halt. Second simplest: a wrapper that absorbs all exceptions and does nothing, as @user2079303 suggests. From either of these defaults you can build a more sophisticated interface. And remember: you can always avoid exceptions by not passing "bad" data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper for the library that catches all exceptions thrown by the library. Compile the library and the wrapper with exceptions enabled. Use the wrapper from the legacy code which has exceptions disabled. This way nothing gets thrown to the code that has exceptions disabled.

```
// third party library
// compiled with exceptions
// may throw
int foo();

// wrapper library
// compiled with exceptions
// may not throw
enum class Error { no_error, code_1, code_2 };

int wrapper_foo(Error& err) {
    try {
         err = Error::no_error;
         return foo();
    } catch(const std::length_error& e) {
        // optionally handle specific exceptions differently
        err = Error::code_1;
        return -1;
    } catch(...) {
        // you must catch all thrown objects
        err = Error::code_2;
        return -1;
    }
}

// legacy code
// compiled without exceptions
void bar() {
    Error err;
    int baz = wrapper_foo(err);
    if(err != Error::no_error) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-isystem` to include third-party

==================edit====================
`-fno-exceptions` was used to compile my project, and i have to add a third-party library that uses exceptions. in this case can use `-isystem` to include third-party library.

Comment: `-isystem` has nothing to do with exceptions. OP was interested in how to handle exceptions in third-party code in software that essentially does not use exceptions.